# Rendering a screen on icon tap

Tags: dart, flutter

I am still not able to get an icon tap to cause the redrawing of an app screen. I am using the Vanilla project on GitHub as a guide. I have obviously missed something!

The app displays 9 circles in a GridView. main.dart contains runApp(CirclesApp());. CirclesApp (in circlesapp.dart) contains code to display the 9 circles by invoking Circles (in circles.dart). CirclesApp creates the AppState (in appstate.dart) that will be passed to Circles. CirclesApp contains the AppBar that has the icon that, when tapped, invokes the function flash_all_tiles(). That function iterates through the 9 tiles, setting the flash_tile value to the index of the current tile and delays for 500 ms. The timer time-out function resets the flash_tile value to -1.

What I had hoped to see, upon tapping the AppBar Icons.replay icon, was each circle flash in turn. I do see a change in the Home Bar buttons, but no change to the brightness of each circle. The color of each circle is determined by the create_circle_tiles function (in circles.dart) by comparing the current tile index to widget.appState.flash_tile.

The code for the app follows. The files circle_colors.dart, constants.dart, and strings.dart are not included.

main.dart:

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
// ignore_for_file: constant_identifier_names
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'circlesapp.dart';

void main() => runApp(CirclesApp());
```

circlesapp.dart:

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
// ignore_for_file: constant_identifier_names
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:async';

import 'appstate.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'circles.dart';
import 'strings.dart';

class CirclesApp extends StatefulWidget {

  CirclesApp();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {return CirclesAppState();
  }
} // class CirclesApp

class CirclesAppState extends State<CirclesApp> {
  AppState appState = AppState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setState(() {
      appState = AppState(flash_tile: -1);
    });
  } // initState()

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: Strings.appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(Strings.appTitle),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.replay),
              onPressed: () => flash_all_tiles(),
            )
          ]
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Circles (
              appState: appState,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Timer start_flash_timeout(Duration duration) {
    return new Timer(duration, on_flash_timeout);
  } // start_flash_timeout

  void on_flash_timeout() {
    setState((){
      appState.flash_tile  = -1;
    });
  } // on_flash_timeout

  void flash_all_tiles(){
    for ( int i = 0; ( i < Constants.NUMBER_TILES); i++){
      setState(() {
        appState.flash_tile = i;
      });
      start_flash_timeout(Constants.TILE_FLASH_DURATION);
    }
  }

} // class CirclesAppState
```

appstate.dart:

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
// ignore_for_file: constant_identifier_names
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

class AppState {
  int flash_tile;

  AppState({
    this.flash_tile = -1,
  });

  void set_flash_tile ( int flash_tile) {
    this.flash_tile = flash_tile;
  } // set_flash_tile

  @override
  String toString() {
    return ( 'AppState{flash_tile: $flash_tile}');
  } // toString()

} // class AppState
```

circles.dart:

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
// ignore_for_file: constant_identifier_names
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'appstate.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'circle_colors.dart';

class Circles extends StatefulWidget {
  final AppState appState;

  Circles({
    @required this.appState,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return Circles_State();
  }
} // class Circles

class Circles_State extends State<Circles> {
  List<GridTile>  grid_tiles = <GridTile>[];

  Circles_State();

  GridTile new_circle_tile(Color tile_color,
                           int   index) {
    GridTile tile = GridTile(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: tile_color,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
          ),
        )
      );
    return (tile);
  } // new_circle_tile

  List<GridTile> create_circle_tiles() {
    grid_tiles = new List<GridTile>();

    for (int i = 0; (i < Constants.NUMBER_TILES); i++) {
      Color tile_color = ( widget.appState.flash_tile == i) ?
          Circle_Colors.bright_colors[i] :
          Circle_Colors.normal_colors[i];

      grid_tiles.add(new_circle_tile(tile_color, i));
    }
    return (grid_tiles);
  } // create_circle_tiles

  @override // Circles_State
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: Constants.CROSS_AXIS_COUNT,
      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      mainAxisSpacing: Constants.MAIN_AXIS_SPACING,
      crossAxisSpacing: Constants.CROSS_AXIS_SPACING,
      children: create_circle_tiles(),
    );
  }
} // class Circles_State
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is within your `flash_all_tiles()`method. `setState()` is called for every loop value, but the end result, when the new frame is built, is that the value it holds is the one of the last iteration, so you are not able to see the animation.

This is easier implemented with an animation. Use the following code for the `CirclesAppState` and you will see it animate.

```
class CirclesAppState extends State<CirclesApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation animation;

  AppState appState = AppState(flash_tile: -1);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
    animation = IntTween(begin: -1, end: Constants.NUMBER_TILES).animate(controller)
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        appState = AppState(flash_tile: animation.value);
      });
    })
    ..addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        controller.reverse();
      }
    });

  } // initState()

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Title",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Title"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.replay),
                onPressed: () => flash_all_tiles(),
              )
            ]
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Circles (
              appState: appState,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void flash_all_tiles(){
    controller.forward();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. You alerted me to the animation API which I studied and fixed my code. I also used https://sergiandreplace.com/flutter-animations-the-basics/ in my studies. You also made me reconsider my architecture. I revised it so that Circles now contains the animation since no others need it. So thanks again. Your answer put me on the right path.